# How to use native sqlite3.c file for opening the db

Tags: android, c, native-methods

I wanted to use typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3; for using

```
int sqlite3_open(
const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

and passing sqlite3 object for opening the db

```
package com.kosh.offline;

public class NativeLib {
static {
System.loadLibrary("sqlite3");
}



public native int sqlite3_open(String filename,Object sqlite3);


}
```

Thanks for considering

Comment: ... and what is the problem when try to use it?

Comment: how to pass sqlite3 object from java to c?